# Remove Map Node from vert.x JsonObject serialized String

Tags: json, vert.x

[Vert.x JsonObject Serialized String contains Map and empty filed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeRf7.png)

The structure of the Object I want to serialize is

```java
public class MongoDatasourceResponse {

    private Mongoresponse response;
    private List<JsonObject> data;
    private int size;
    private Error error;

    //get, set method...
}
```

Vert.x JsonObject Serialized String contains "Map" and "empty" filed, But I do not want to have all these extra "map" and "empty" nodes. What I can I do to remove them?

```
{
    "code": -1,
    "data": [
        {
            "map": {
                "n": 0,
                "writeErrors": {
                    "list": [
                        {
                            "map": {
                                "index": 0,
                                "code": 11000,
                                "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: _id_ dup key: { : 5 }"
                            },
                            "empty": false
                        },
                        {
                            "map": {
                                "index": 1,
                                "code": 11000,
                                "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: _id_ dup key: { : 6 }"
                            },
                            "empty": false
                        },
                        {
                            "map": {
                                "index": 2,
                                "code": 11000,
                                "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: _id_ dup key: { : 3 }"
                            },
                            "empty": false
                        },
                        {
                            "map": {
                                "index": 3,
                                "code": 11000,
                                "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: _id_ dup key: { : 7 }"
                            },
                            "empty": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "empty": false
                },
                "ok": 1.0
            },
            "empty": false
        }
    ],
    "size": 0,
    "error": null
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `.encode()` method?

Comment: Please also post how are you trying to serialize your object, not only the output.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Thaks! I updated the object I want to serialize in question body, and the output part I want to modify is the `List<JsonObject> data`.

Comment: @mintuhouse I rided  to register two MessageCodec List and the Object class I want to serialize.